# Why did I lose this hand?

Tags: texas-hold-em, reading-hands, hand

I was playing hold 'em and there was a show down.

The board was:

K:diamonds: 2:diamonds: J:diamonds: 8:diamonds: 6:diamonds:

My opponent had:

9:diamonds: T:diamonds:

and I had:

7:spades: J:clubs:

I thought this would have resulted in a tie because we both had a king high flush but I lost? Is there some rule I'm missing?

Answer (score 19):

In all poker hands not only the highest card determinates the better hand, all cards do.

The best five card hand you can form is K:diamonds: J:diamonds: 8:diamonds: 6:diamonds: 2:diamonds: (which is the board).

The best hand your opponent can form however is  K:diamonds: J:diamonds: T:diamonds: 9:diamonds: 8:diamonds:

So, while you both have the King and the Jack, he has the Ten as the third best card, which is better than your third best card, which is the Eight.