# Should this hold'em pot be split?

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules, reading-hands

Say I have a 10 and Q. Opponent has a 10 and K.

On the table there is 10 2 3 4 A

Is this a split pot, as we both have a pair of 10s, and then we both use the Ace?

Or does the tie-breaker always have to come from our own hand, so the King beats the Queen?

Comment: Poker hands have exactly five cards, no more, no less. Whether they are in your hand or not doesn't matter in hold'em.  In this case, 10-10-A-K-4 beats 10-10-A-Q-4. If, for example, the deuce on the board were paired, then you would split because 10-10-2-2-A ties 10-10-2-2-A, and the K doesn't play.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- your hand is: pair of Tens + Ace kicker 1 + Queen kicker 2
- opponent hand: pair of Tens + Ace kicker 1 + King kicker 2

So your opponent wins.

I really don't want to be rude, but please google it next time, I'm sure you would've found the answer.

Comment: Thanks Radu. I had searched this site first, but only found answers about when the best 5 cards are all on the table.

Comment: @DarrenCook OK, fair enough :)

Answer (score 2):

You hand is always the best **five** card hand you can make, so in this case:

```
Your hand is : Pair of 10's with an Ace, Queen, and 4
Their hand is: Pair of 10's with an Ace, King , and 4
```

The King beats the Queen, so their hand is best; they win the pot. The 4 is also relevant since it is part of the best 5 card hand you can make.

A tie occurs only if your best five card hands are the same. Suppose the board was:

```
10 A K Q 2
```

Then if you had 10 9, and your opponent had 10 3, you would tie since you would both have:

```
Pair of 10's with an Ace, King, and Queen
```

The 9 you have is irrelevant since it isn't part of your best 5 card hand.

If you always think "best 5 cards" it becomes easy to tell when to apply kickers and when not too. For example a full house is a five card hand, so having a full house with an Ace kicker is meaningless. If two players have the same full house, then they tie (assuming no better hands).