# Who wins the pot or will it be a Split?

Tags: rules

ok so my mate has pocket 5s and I had J8, the cards on the board were KK8QQ who wins this or is it a split?? and explain why please

Comment: Duplicate questions are duplicate, we need to close them because they are already answered.

Answer (score 0):

Hero  J8
Villain  55
Board  KKQQ8

Best **5** cards every time

Hero  KKQQJ
Villain  KKQQ8

Hero wins with a higher kicker

When the boards has 2 higher pair like that then the pair in the hand is counterfeited.

[Hand Order](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/6680/how-to-determine-the-winning-hands-in-poker)