# Two straights and a pair who wins?

Tags: texas-hold-em

We are new to playing poker. We played Texas holdem a few nights ago. Tow played got a straight. Player 1 J-7. Player 2 10-6. Normally we would have given it to player 1 for having a higher straight, but player 2 also had a pair of 6s. So we gave it to player 2.

Comment: Best 5 cards every times

Comment: I don't see how you could have a straight and a pair, since a straight is already 5 cards and a poker hand is also 5 cards.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that matters is the best 5 cards.

So Player 1 can make J-7, while at the same time Player 2 can make 10-6 and pair of 6.

Player's 1 best hand is straight J-7. That is the **ONLY** thing we consider.
Player's 2 best hand is straight 10-6. That is the **ONLY** thing we consider. The pair of 6 is not considered.

Player 1's J-7 beats Player 2's 10-6, so player 1 wins.

When in doubt, remembers this: **only the best hand you consider...even in tie**

If the best hand of both player is the same, then split the pot. Don't consider the second best hand or whatsoever.

More at: [How to determine the winning hands in poker?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/6680/how-to-determine-the-winning-hands-in-poker)