# Which pair wins the hand?

Tags: rules

If I have a pair of Aces in my hand and the other player has a 4 and a Jack in his hand, and the community cards are a Jack, 8, 10, 5 and 2. Who wins?

Answer (score 0):

Each player's hand ONLY consists of their best 5 cards, community cards being 'shared'.

Your Hand: A-A-J-T-8 (one pair, Aces)

Their Hand: J-J-T-8-4 (one pair, Jacks)

One pair of Aces beats one pair of Jacks, you win.

Learn hand rankings from [this question](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/6680/how-to-determine-the-winning-hands-in-poker/6681#6681).