# Which poker hand is the winner?

Tags: poker-strategy

Dealers poker hand: 4,4,4,6,9 and My poker hand: 10,J,Q,K,8 so which hand is the winner? Which one is higher ?

Comment: It's not possible to tell for sure unless you include the suits, as per my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`4 4 4 6 9` beats `T J Q K 8` because `4 4 4 6 9` is Three Of A Kind and `T J Q K 8` is High Card (King). This is assuming the `T J Q K 8` is not a flush - you have not specified suits, so it is impossible to tell. If the `T J Q K 8` is all the same suit, then that hand wins as a Flush beats Three Of A Kind.

For more information, see the [How to determine the winning hands in poker?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/6680/how-to-determine-the-winning-hands-in-poker) question which [Nij](https://poker.stackexchange.com/users/4121/nij) linked to in the comments.