# Who wins when two players both have a flush?

Tags: rules, reading-hands

Who wins when two players have a flush?

For example, say the first player also has two pair, one in their hand (two 3's), and one on the board (two 8's). The second player has `AQ`, with the same pair on the board (two 8's). Player one completes the flush with one of the threes in their hand. Player two completes the flush with the ace in their hand. The highest card in the flush on the board is a Jack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information you've given, whereby:

> Player 1: `3w 3x`
>
> Player 2: `Aw Qx`
>
> Board: `8x 8w Jw Yw Zw`

*where w is any single specific suit, x represents any non-w suit any and Y/Z are each some rank below J*

then the best 5 card hand held by each player is:

> Player 1: `Jw Yw Zw 8w 3w` - Flush, Jack high
>
> Player 2: `Aw Jw Yw Zw 8w` - Flush, Ace high

Therefore, **Player 2 wins**.

As mentioned in the comments, you could have answered this question yourself by reading [How to determine the winning hands in poker?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/6680/how-to-determine-the-winning-hands-in-poker).

Answer (score 0):

Player 2 wins. Once you have a flush, 2 pair doesnt really matter.
So, flush with highest card... in this case Ace for second player wins.