# Both players has full house, who should win?

Tags: texas-hold-em, reading-hands, showdown

We were playing texas hold'em and the cards on the table ended with 3 jacks and a couple of 4's.

On my hand was a pair of six. My opponent had a 4 and an 8. The other 2 folded

My opponent said that I had no cards connected on the table so that he should've won.

Thus, I wanted to ask the experts here who truly should've won.

Comment: You won your hand was jjj66, your opponent hand is jjj44.

Answer (score 0):

Board: `J J J 4 4`

Player 1: `6 6`

Player 2: `4 8`

Player 1's best hand is `J J J 6 6` (Full house, Jacks full of Sixes)

Player 2's best hand is `J J J 4 4` (Full house, Jacks full of Fours)

Therefore, **Player 1 wins**.

You could have answered this question yourself by reading [How to determine the winning hands in poker?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/6680/how-to-determine-the-winning-hands-in-poker) - this question will probably be closed as a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Thanks for that mate. I prolly should've done more research but didn't know exactly what to type on the search bar so I apologize for that. Really appreciate what you did though.

Comment: No problem at all - it's not super-trivial to find the [How to determine the winning hands in poker?](http://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/6680/how-to-determine-the-winning-hands-in-poker) question if you're looking for a specific answer about a particular instance. If you found the answer helpful, feel free to upvote and/or accept it. Welcome to Poker.SE!