# Who is the winner from the image below

Tags: texas-hold-em

A final hand after the river:

[image: hand]

Wondering who wins?

Answer (score 2):

A♠2♠ wins with a best 5 card hand of: A♠A♥9♠9♥5♥ (Two pair, Aces and Nines).

4♠5♠ loses with a best 5 cards hand of: 9♠9♥5♠5♥A♥ (Two pair, Nines and Fives).

You could have answered your own question by reading [this question](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/6680/how-to-determine-the-winning-hands-in-poker) and its answers.