# Taking the second card in poker as the highest card

Tags: drawing

Hi I'm not too sure about this.

Player 1: K⋄ Q⋄

Player 2: K♣ J♣

On the table: T⋄ J♥ Q♣ A♣ 8⋄

Who would win in this situation as player 1 has a higher second card but then when you consider the 5 highest cards of each hand it's a direct tie.
Any help with this would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: In poker you can use five out of the seven cards to make your hand. Therefore there is no such thing as 'a straight with a kicker'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a split pot, as both players have a straight (TJQKA) as their best hand - there are no kickers involved.

As mentioned in the comments, there is an existing question [here](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/6680/how-to-determine-the-winning-hands-in-poker) which deals with how to evaluate hands against each other to determine the outcome of a hand and explains how the pot should be awarded.