# Who wins or is it a split pot

Tags: texas-hold-em

[image]

The 5 cards on table: A,9,9,3,Q
My cards : A,10
his cards:  A,6

Who wins and can you explain

Answer (score 1):

this is a split pot because both players best 5-card hand is a two pair (Aces and Nines) with a queen kicker. If the queen on the river was a lower card than a ten (say a seven) then A-10 would win this hand.

Comment: see https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/6680/how-to-determine-the-winning-hands-in-poker