# What are the odds of the river containing a full house?

Tags: probability

I was watching a game in a bar the other day and the river ended up containing a full house. What are the odds of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just the odds of a 5 card hand.
0.1441% = 693 : 1

[Poker probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability)

[Determine winning hand](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/6680/how-to-determine-the-winning-hands-in-poker)