# Top 5 Cards Question (Straight)

Tags: texas-hold-em

It was down to a friend and I in poker, the 5 cards drawn was Q K J 10 9
my buddy had an Ace and a 7, I had a King and an 8. Would this pot have been a split or would my buddy or I won it all. (Suit did not matter in this hand). It was just confusing to me because the straight was already there on the table.

Comment: This Q has already an answer [here](https://poker.stackexchange.com/q/6680/5310) and no, it isn't a split :)

Answer (score 1):

Your buddy will win the hand. His final hand would be 10 J Q K A , which is a 'higher' straight than yours (9 10 J Q K)