# Who win this hand and why? Thanks!

Tags: texas-hold-em

[image]

Please see screenshot below, thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate. Please check out this post: https://poker.stackexchange.com/q/6680/5050

Comment: Screen is correct. JJJ88 defeats 888KK.

Answer (score 2):

In poker you can choose 5 out of the 7 cards to make your hand. One player has JJJ88, the other has 888KK. If two player have full houses the rank of the three of a kind is looked at first. Since a jack is higher than an 8, the guy with pocket jacks wins.