# There is straight on the board

Tags: poker-strategy, hand

On the board there is 8 9 10 J Q
Player 1 has AQ
Player 2 has J9
Player 3 has J9
Who wins?

Comment: What's the highest 5-card hand each player can make?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine the winning hands in poker?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/6680/how-to-determine-the-winning-hands-in-poker)

Answer (score 1):

This pot will be split between all three players since no one can make a better straight than one on the board.

P.S. - If someone would hold Kx, he would make a higher straight and take the pot.