# Two players have two pairs. Who wins?

Tags: poker-theory

On the board is ( 10,10,Ace,8,6)

Player one has (Ace, Jack)

Player two has (Ace,3)

Both players have a two pair who wins?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine the winning hands in poker?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/6680/how-to-determine-the-winning-hands-in-poker)

Answer (score 4):

The winning hand is determined by who has the best five cards. The best five cards for player 1 is: Ace, Ace, 10, 10, J (two pair, Jack kicker). The best five cards for player 2 is: Ace, Ace, 10, 10, 8 (two pair, eight kicker). Since a Jack ranks higher than an eight, player one has the better hand and wins.