# I need to know who wins on texas hold em

Tags: texas-hold-em

These are the table cards 3 k k 9 9

My hand A-J and my opponent has 8-8 who wins?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine the winning hands in poker?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/6680/how-to-determine-the-winning-hands-in-poker)

Comment: What are the best five cards in your hand? What are the best five cards in your opponents hand? Think about it, it is very simple and straight forward. Does kings over nines with an 8 beat kings over nine with an ace?

Comment: Poker hands have *exactly five cards*. Your K-K-9-9-A beats his K-K-9-9-8.