# Who wins this hand of Texas Holden poker

Tags: hand

I have king. and jack.the other guy has ace. queen.and on the table is ace. ten. ten. ten. ten. who wins

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine the winning hands in poker?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/6680/how-to-determine-the-winning-hands-in-poker)

Comment: Split pot. Read how to determine winning hands in poker for full explanation.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in either of your hole cards that improves what's on the board, so you both have the same best hand and you split the pot.