# Two Pair Question

Tags: texas-hold-em

So me and my buddies where playing poker and they both had 2 pair one had a 9 as the fifth card and one had an 8 but there was an ace on the board which is higher than both there 8 and 9.

Is it a spilt pot or does the player with the 9 in there hand win?

Comment: You need to be more specific: show us the actual hands and complete board. I'd just be guessing at this point that the Ace kick on board probably plays, making it a split pot (in Hold'em, it is never important whether cards are in your hand or on the board). To know for sure, you need to provide details.

Comment: so one player had King and a 9 and the other had a king and a 8

Comment: the board had a king ,6,6,Ace,2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine the winning hands in poker?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/6680/how-to-determine-the-winning-hands-in-poker)

Comment: Yep. You're both playing KK66A.