# I don't understand why we lose with a flush, when you have 6 cards with the same symbol

Tags: flush

sorry for the approximate translation (I don't speak English and i use Google Translate) but I don't understand why when we have a flush from the flop for example if the turn or the river is of the same symbol as our flush we are losing. I know that a hand in poker is made up of 5 cards but suddenly we just have to take the 5 which suits us right? Twice I have seen this on TV during tournaments.

I searched in French, in English and I did not find the answer. There is no mention that explains this.
In the video, the commentator at the time of the flop was saying "let's pray that the player does not have a 6th card of the same symbol that falls on the turn or the river. At the moment of the river the player lost when he had 100% for the victory.

For exemple :

- Player 1 : 9♠J♠ 100% win
- Player 2 : K♦K♥ 0% win

Table : 3♠5♠Q♠2♥

For exemple :

- Player 1 : 9♠J♠ 0% win
- Player 2 : K♦K♥ 100% win

Table : 3♠5♠Q♠2♥A♠

The Player 2 win. Can you explain me please ?

However in this video a man wins when there are 6 cards of the same symbol at 4:13
Link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XEe3LCL34Tg

Is it different when you have a straight flush ?

Sorry again if this is a long message but for several days I have been thinking without understanding...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine the winning hands in poker?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/6680/how-to-determine-the-winning-hands-in-poker)

Answer (score 1):

In your example, player 1 has a flush AQJ95 (spades) and player 2 has a pair of kings only (KKAQ5) and will lose the hand.

If player 2 in your example has the King of spades, then player 2 would have a better flush on the river (AKQ53 > AQJ95).

The video you showed is an example of a straight flush, a straight flush is an entirely different hand that ranks higher than a flush. This hand requires 5 cards of the same suit and in ranking order (such as 89TJQ all spades).