# Same river flush with pairs

Tags: texas-hold-em

My friend had heart6 and heart10 and i had par diamond jack

And the ”river” was diamond 6, diamond 10, diamond 3, diamond 7, diamond 9

So my friend had pari in 6 and 10 with flush in the river. And i had Pair jacks with flush in river

Who win this? I an so confused

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine the winning hands in poker?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/6680/how-to-determine-the-winning-hands-in-poker)

Comment: You had the highest flush. Ignore pairs here only the flushes count, which of you had the highest flush you did. When there are five to a flush on board, all you need to win the pot when you hold a flush card and your opponent does not, is a flush card higher then the lowest flush card on board.