# Why did i lose this hand even if it looks as i was winning?

Tags: poker-theory, poker-stars, pokertracker

It is still unclear why i lost this hand. Anyone more insights? I have the pair of 4 [image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine the winning hands in poker?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/6680/how-to-determine-the-winning-hands-in-poker)

Answer (score 1):

The short version is: your 4's got 'counterfeited'.

Your best 5 cards play, out of the 7 cards available.

The 9's and 7's make the best two pair, so the pair of 4's don't play. Since you have to use 5 cards total, you use the single card that is the best of the remaining 3 cards. That best card for you is the 10 on the table. Your hand is two pair, 9's & 7's, with a 10 kicker.

The other players each have an ace, so they can both use their aces as their kicker card, which is better than your kicker card. So the other two players 'chop the pot'.

If you had had a pocket pair of anything higher than 7's, or at least one 7, 9 or 10, you would have won. You also could have won if you had 8,J or 6,8. Those are the only cards you could have had that would have beat the other two hands.