# Would 2 pairs of aces and king beat 3 of a kind of king

Tags: poker-theory

I had in my hands a pair of aces.

The table card had 2 kings and 3 low numbers

My opponent had a king and 10 in his hand

Basically I had 2 pairs of aces and kings and he had three of a kind of kings

Who wins in that case

Comment: Any three of a kind beats any two pair, so your opponent wins. The Wikipedia article on Poker explains the hand rankings well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine the winning hands in poker?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/6680/how-to-determine-the-winning-hands-in-poker)

Answer (score 0):

The hand rankings in poker are as follows:

1. High card
2. One pair
3. Two pair
4. Trips
5. Straight
6. Flush
7. Full house
8. Quads
9. Straight flush

The opponent in this case would have the better hand because he had three of a kind (trips) whereas you had two pair. In Texas Hold 'em each player uses the best five cards among their two hole cards and five community cards. In this case you would have AAKK with the highest other card dealt on the board acting as your kicker. Your opponent had KKKT with the same kicker.