# Can a community pair is used as kicker to break tie?

Tags: rules

I got a strange situation in last night play. I had J5, player B had J4. the board was J9977. No suits in this case. I thought I had JJ995 and player B had JJ994, and I won. But other players believed the 3rd pair 77 should be used as kicker and we tie. Can you please let me know who is correct? Can a pair in community board be treated as single card to break the tie? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine the winning hands in poker?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/6680/how-to-determine-the-winning-hands-in-poker)

Answer (score 1):

No, but yes. A poker hand consists of five cards, always. There is no such thing as using a third pair as a kicker. However, you did in fact tie, since both had the same hand: JJ997.