# Why is the winning hand a A-high flush?

Tags: omaha, flush

In a home game of Omaha, the board is: J♦ T♦ 8♦ 6♦ K♣. Winning hand took the pot with a flush with his A♦ 3♦. If both cards have to play how can the three be played in place if all higher cards?

Comment: Have a look at the first bulleted example under 'Explanation' here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omaha_hold_%27em#:~:text=A%20player%20with%202%E2%99%A0%203%E2%99%A0%20K%E2%99%A6%20J%E2%99%A6%20can%20play%20the%20spade%20flush.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine the winning hands in poker?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/6680/how-to-determine-the-winning-hands-in-poker)

Answer (score 0):

Some specific things to notice about Omaha hands are:

> As in Texas hold 'em, three or more suited cards on the board makes a flush possible, but unlike that game, **a player always needs two of that suit in hand to play a flush**. [Omaha hold'em](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omaha_hold_%27em#Explanation)

In your case, you need to keep the A♦3♦ and pick three diamonds from the board (the 3 highest ones): J♦T♦8♦